# Taking a fullpage screenshot using Selenium server in python

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot

I am trying to take a full page screenshot of a url using selenium using python
I have found plenty of examples for webdriver but I am more interested in using it through
the server. Is it possible if yes, can anyone point me in the right direction? The reason I am interested in the server version is to reduce load, do multi request processing and possibly not have to load X if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The captureEntirePageScreenshot command through Selenium IDE is exported like this into Python 2 (Remote Control)

```
sel.capture_entire_page_screenshot("entirePageScreenshot.png", "")
```